# Missing claims from AppFabricLabs

Tags: claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I created rules for "name" and "emailaddress" claims in appfabriclabs' ACS for Windows Live, Facebook, Google and Yahoo... however on the Relying Party side, WIF doesn't seem to see them... I see `nameidentifier` and `identityprovider` but nothing else.

is there something else I need in ACS to make this work?  how can I check that the claims are actually in there?

*** Update ***

Apparently, only Windows Live is failing; the other providers return me the claims I configured.  Also, the claim for e-mail address (for example) I configured manually since ACS didn't have it... I entered the type as `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` and indicated it as a passthrough... does Windows Live not provide e-mail addresses?

*** Update II ***

well... as per [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/b2d2e62d-1a93-43bd-9717-a82fd63ed3cd/) I can't just configure it; I'm going to have to do some other voodoo to get at it... but there must be some way to get more than the /nameidentifier/ because when I log into websites using Windows Live ID I'm shown as being logged in as "ekkis" - anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless you are developing an app inside MSFT, LiveID can only supply a nameidentitifier. This is by design. if you want to use LiveID and need an e-mail, you need to ask the user for it and then correlate nameidentifier <-> e-mail yourself.

Comment: hei @Eugenio! I did find there's a Javascript API for LiveID.  I started down an implementation attempt but haven't been able to make it work... see SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810831/liveid-api-fails-missing-token